# Div does not show the css

Tags: html, css

I don't find my problem:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
#content {
  position: relative;
}
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 215px;
}
#callAction {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 38px 110px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="overlay">
    <a id="callAction">Button<a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The CSS of the a-tag works, but not the css of the div-tag with the id #overlay.
What is the problem here??

Comment: Judging by the z-index values, you have a stacking problem. Not sure why you are positioning the link at all but without understanding what it is you are trying to achieve it's hard to comment further.

Comment: would you be able to tell us what your desired result is?

Comment: my result is, that the div container doesn't have the attributes of the id.
And i positioning the link, because without that it is below the slider (after the div container with the id #overlay), the slider just have the position relative. It's a wordpress plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rash805115/wwu9vu55/) example I made. I cannot understand your problem clearly, but from the comments, I recon that you want to place your button in the middle of the #overlay div.

In the CSS of #callaction I just added the top and left to keep it centered.

```
#callAction {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 38px 110px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
}
```

Feel free to edit this fiddle to let me know your exact problem.

**Also did you know** that your `<a>` tag is not closed.

## Edit

From the comments below, I understand that the user needs to have a wrapper div called container which will have some height: in his case full height and width of the page. Then he has #overlay div which he needs to place "relative" to the parent div.

Here was the problem, when you made your #overlay div "absolute", then it is no longer in the common layout, but is placed outside the layout. Read CSS positioning [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

So all you need to do is not make the child div's absolute. Keep them relative. Just like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rash805115/wwu9vu55/2/).

## Edit 2:

The final issue turned out to be `wrong comment` syntax. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp) for comments.

Comment: Yeah, the a-tag is just a typing mistake.
I want to place the container #overlay in the middle of another container. So I need the attributes.

Comment: @KeylaRainbow so tell me if I am wrong. you want to place overlay inside content in such a way that overlay is centered ? Also the callAction must be centered in overlay? something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/rash805115/wwu9vu55/1/

Comment: Yes! Just two points: #overlay don't need to be centered in content, content is like a wrapper-div. I just need give #overlay a exactly place with top and left. and the callAction don't need to be centered.
like that example: http://bragthemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/FullSlide-Homepage.png

Comment: @KeylaRainbow okay. So you want #overlay to be placed "inside" #content. Inside means that when #content moves, the #overlay moves it it. And the top and left of #overlay must be "relative" to #content...right?

Comment: Well, yes! Just that content has 100% width and height, like the body.

Comment: Thanks for your support! Today I found my fail: 
I had a wrong comment in the css file: The // works on js, php, less but not in css, that's what I has forgotten. Argh, damn little things! 
Thank you really for your help!

Comment: @KeylaRainbow no problem. We learn little little every day. I will also update my answer with this information.